# Disabling auto suggestion in UIKeyboard using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

Whenever I enter any text in the textview in iPhone app by default the `UIKeyboard` shows auto suggestion. I want to only hide the auto suggestion in keyboard.

tried with all these options but it doesn't works:

- UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo
- UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone
- UITextSpellCheckingTypeNo

Comment: Are you setting the option in the storyboard or in code? If code, include it in your post.

Answer (score 3):

The `autoCorrection` property must be set to `NO`. If you are using storyboards, just set it there for the `textFields` in question.